# How to hyphenate an adjective+noun+gerund adjective compound?

Tags: hyphens, compounds

We're used to adjective compounds, such as:

> a **decision-making** process

or

> a  **cancer-causing** lotion.

But what if I want to add an adjective to the noun?

For example:

> a **corporate decision-making** process. (A process to make corporate decisions)

Or

> A **malignant cancer-causing** lotion. (A lotion that causes malignant cancer)

Should I put an hyphen between "corporate" and "decision", and between "malignant" and "cancer"?

Comment: Use a hyphen whenever not doing so would lead to ambiguity, and use it to join the two most related words.

Comment: A malignant cancer-causing lotion - could be interpreted as though the lotion is malignant , I would opt for A malignant-cancer-causing lotion. I'd be included to say that about decision making too, but I think it's all about context and most people will understand your meaning.